# Drop rows to another dataframe using pd.drop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to drop rows based on multiple conditions. I am able to successfully drop the rows from the dataframe but I'm having trouble when I try to drop the rows to another dataframe(append the rows to another dataframe).

This works perfectly:

```py
dfAntrags = dfAntrags.drop(dfAntrags.loc[dfAntrags['Sachnr-null'] == True].index & ((dfAntrags.loc[dfAntrags['Difference-up'] == 0].index) | (dfAntrags.loc[dfAntrags['Difference-down'] == 0].index)))
```

This doesn't work properly:

```py
dfFaulty_claims = dfAntrags.drop(dfAntrags.loc[dfAntrags['Sachnr-null'] == True].index & ((dfAntrags.loc[dfAntrags['Difference-up'] == 0].index) | (dfAntrags.loc[dfAntrags['Difference-down'] == 0].index)))
```

The latter code appends ALL the rows from "dfAntrags" to "dfFaulty_claims", not just the ones which should be filtered based on the condition and it also doesn't drop those rows from dfAntrags.

Is there some logic that I am missing out on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the index, then drop and you dont have to use `index`'s and `loc`'s in the filter statement, try:

```
idx = dfAntrags[(dfAntrags['Sachnr-null'] == True) & ((dfAntrags['Difference-up'] == 0) | (dfAntrags['Difference-down'] == 0))].index
```

First `append` (in this case `concat`):

```
dfFaulty_claims = pd.concat([dfFaulty_claims, dfAntrags.loc[idx, :]])
```

And finally `drop`:

```
dfAntrags = dfAntrags.drop(idx)
```

Hope it works!